# User sort by last_modified_date always return errors

Tags: support, users, sort

I am using this API to get users info sorting by last_modified date, https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users#page=1&pagesize=100&order=asc&sort=modified&filter=!9YdnSBVWs&site=stackoverflow&run=true.  I have three questions:

1. What is the meaning of last_modified_date? Users updated his/her user profile or name?
2. The filter is returning all the fields, but the API does not return the last_modified_date field.
3. Sorting by last_modified_date will always give me some errors even
   I did not call many times.  However, sorting by creation_date is working great.

Comment: What errors, exactly?  I don't see anything obviously wrong.

Comment: I am not calling many times, but I got this error {"error_id":502,"error_message":"Violation of backoff parameter","error_name":"throttle_violation"}